# Android String.replace not working

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to replace a character of a string with another character but not able to do that.I have used String function for this
Code.

```
String text;
text="2:15";
if(text.contains(":"))
{
    replace(":",".");
}
Log.i("Tag",text);
```

I want to change 2:15 to 2.15, but it remains the same.

Comment: `text.replace(":",".")`

Comment: don't u need escape character which is \\?

Comment: code is in java? because `containe`  method not available in java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String text;
text= "2:15";
if(text.contains(":"))
{
    replace(":","."); // Will not cause anything as String is immutable. 
}
Log.i("Tag",text);
```

Change to

```
String text;
text="2:15";
if(text.contains(":")){
   text = text.replace(":",".");
}
Log.i("Tag",text);
```

Read up on Strings and their immutable property.

Comment: Is `containe` is right method ?

Comment: Thanks Prosper, that was a copy paste error :D

Comment: is `text=2:15;`valid statement for creating String ?

Comment: Thanks Once more Prosper :D

Comment: Correct you need assign to use :)

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Java - replace doesn't change the existing string, it returns a new one. You want:

```
String text="2:15";
if(text.contain(":"))
{
    text = text.replace(":",".");
}
Log.i("Tag",text);
```

Comment: Is containe is right method ? –

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yeah dat was mistake sry i edited it

Comment: is text=2:15; valid statement for creating String ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yeah man once again

Comment: @akaElement your text variable does not have type which is String. hope u see that

Comment: 1 for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code

```
String text = "2:15";
text = text.replace(":",".");
```

- `text.replace(":",".");` returns you a new string, therefore you have to assign it to some variable. `text` in this case.
- I also removed `text.contains(":")` because it is an un-necessary call, replace will end up replacing nothing if it dont contains the string to be replaced.

Comment: if you can explain why? I'll vote u up

Comment: @KickButtowski When you call replace(this,that) you end up with a totally new String. If you want to keep this new copy, you need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: plz add this explanation to your post so I can vote u up